# What is the issue with this sql CREATE TABLE command?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to move a schema from **mysql5.6** to **mysql5.5**.

I exported the schema from v5.6 to a `.sql` file, and when trying to import the file to v5.5, I'm getting an error, but I do not know what the error is since sql reports all errors as `error in sql syntax`.
Here is my create command, I hope someone can help figure out what is going wrong ?
The error is in this create command only, hence posting only the relevant part here

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `status_change_logs`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `status_change_logs` (
  `entry_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `match_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` smallint(4) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` datetime(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`entry_id`),
  KEY `match_id` (`match_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=102273 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

Error

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 897: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`entry_id`),
  KEY `match_id` (`match_id`)
) ENGINE' at line 5

Operation failed with exitcode 1
```

Comment: Why are you going backwards instead of forward to MySQL 8+?

Comment: @GordonLinoff There are some constraints, which I cannot say here. :)

Comment: I believe `datetime` type doesn't take the size in paretheses i.e. it should be `datetime` not `datetime(4)` at least for older versions of mysql.

Comment: @px1mp I should replace all datetime(x) with datetime then ?

Comment: @px1mp Please post your comment as a answer that resolved everything ! Thanks !

Comment: FSP for datetime datatypes was released in MySQL 5.6.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that `datetime` type doesn't take the size in parentheses i.e. it should be

```
`timestamp` datetime NOT NULL,
```

instead of

```
`timestamp` datetime(4) NOT NULL,
```

surely at least for older versions of MySQL.